# Merge two strings letter by letter in Java?

Tags: java, string

> Given two strings, A and B, create a bigger string made of the first char of A, the first char of B, the second char of A, the second char of B, and so on. Any leftover chars go at the end of the result.

```
public String mixString(String a, String b)
{


    String str = "";
    int len = 0;

    if (a.length() >= b.length())
    {
        len = a.length();
    } else
        len = b.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {

        if (i < a.length())
        {
            str += a.charAt(i);
        }

        if (i < b.length())
        {
            str += b.charAt(i);
        }

    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: did you try to use a debugger?

Comment: I don't really know of one. It's an logic error too, it compiles fine.

Comment: debugger will let you go through your code line by line and watch the values of variables, I really recommend learning to use it. Most IDEs (like Eclipse, Intellij IDEA) have some debugger included.

Comment: why do you have cases for when the lengths are different? The only cases you should be concerned about are when a.length = 0, b.length =0, or both of them = 0. Also, these cases should all be in one big loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got a workable approach, but you could significantly simplify it by using a single loop with two counters:

```
int apos = 0, bpos = 0;
while (apos != a.length() || bpos != b.length()) {
    if (apos < a.length()) m += a.charAt(apos++);
    if (bpos < b.length()) m += b.charAt(bpos++);
}
```

In this loop you will "make progress" on each step by advancing `apos`, `bpos`, or both. Once a string runs out of characters, its corresponding `pos` stops advancing. The loop is over when both `pos` reach their ends.

Note: When you need to append to a string in a loop, use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: worth noting that appending to `String` in a loop is not efficient. In real life, use `StringBuilder` for such cases.

Comment: This code has no means of increment? How could this even work? It seems to me that it will either run forever or never.

Comment: @Max I assume that you have figured it out, right? The increment happens in the call of `charAt`, protected by the `if` statement.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ya, I didn't know you could even do that. But by this logic, it does the charAt method with whatever value the pos is assigned to, then increments, right?

Answer (score 1):

I used Merge sort approach to solve this problem. First I converted both the strings into their respective character arrays and then merged both the arrays and converted the array back to a string. You can find my code below,I have tested the code and it is working. Let me know if you have any questions..

```
public String merge(String leftStr, String rightStr) {  
        char[]left = leftStr.toCharArray();
        char[]right = rightStr.toCharArray();
        int nL = left.length;
        int nR= right.length;
        char[] mergeArr= new char[nL+nR];
        int i=0,j=0,k=0;
        int temp =0;
        while(i<nL && j<nR){

            if (temp==0){
                mergeArr[k]=left[i];
                i++;
                temp =1;
            }else{
                mergeArr[k]=right[j];
                j++;
                temp=0;
            }
            k++;            
        }
        while(i<nL){

            mergeArr[k]=left[i]; k++; i++;
        }
        while(j<nR){

            mergeArr[k]=right[j]; k++; j++;
        }


        return new String(mergeArr);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `StringBuilder` and `char[]`.  Works as long as the first is longer than the second, which is guaranteed by the first method.

```
public String mixString(String a, String b) {
    if (b.length() > a.length())
        return mixString(new StringBuilder(b), a.toCharArray(), 0);
    return mixString(new StringBuilder(a), b.toCharArray(), 1);
}

public String mixString(StringBuilder ab, char[] b, int start) {
    int i = 0;
    for (char c : b)
        ab.insert(i++*2 + start, "" + c);
    return ab.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt::

public static String mixString1(String a,String b){

```
    String result="";

    int startValue = 0;
    int increment = 0;

    if(a.length()<=b.length()){

    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){

            result =  result+a.charAt(i)+b.charAt(i);

    }

    }

    else if(a.length()>=b.length()){

        for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++){

                result =  result+a.charAt(i)+b.charAt(i);

        }

        }


    if(a.length()<b.length()){

        startValue= a.length();
        increment = b.length();

    }

    else {

        startValue= b.length();
        increment = a.length();

    }

    if(a.length()<b.length()){

    for(int j=startValue;j<increment;j++){

        result = result+b.charAt(j);

    }
    }
    else if(a.length()>b.length()){

        for(int j=startValue;j<increment;j++){

            result = result+a.charAt(j);

        }


    }

    return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String mixString(String a, String b) {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
int longer = 0;
if (a.length()>b.length()) longer = a.length();
else longer = b.length();
for (int i = 0; i <longer;i++){
if (i<a.length()) sb.append(a.substring(i,i+1));
if (i<b.length()) sb.append(b.substring(i,i+1));
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String mixString(String a, String b) {
  String c="";
  String left="";
  int min;
  if(a.length()>b.length()) {
      min=b.length();
     left=a.substring(b.length(),a.length());
  }
  else {
      min=a.length();
      left=b.substring(a.length(),b.length());
  }

  for(int i=0;i<min;i++) {
      c +=a.substring(i,i+1)+b.substring(i,i+1);

  }   
return c+left;            
}
```

Comment: You should add a description explaining your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Approach, feedback is most welcome

```
void printPattern(String str, String str1){
    int length1 = str.length();
    int length2 = str1.length();
    int i =0;
    String output ="";
    while(length1 > 0 && length2 > 0){
         output += (str.charAt(i)) ;
         output += (str1.charAt(i)) ;
        length1-- ; length2-- ; i++;
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Missing "Any leftover chars go at the end of the result." part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
  public String mixString(String a, String b) {
  int minLength = 0;
  String combination = "";
  String end = "";
  
  if (a.length() < b.length()) {
    minLength = a.length();
    end = b.substring(minLength, b.length());
  } else {
    minLength = b.length();
    end = a.substring(minLength, a.length());
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
    combination = combination + a.substring(i, i+1) + b.substring(i, i+1);
  }
  
  return combination + end;
  
}
```